# How to center floating divs?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I want to center the three divs that appear in the mockup below (all have "float:left").
Is this possible?

I don't mind having wrapper-divs.

Text-align:center and display:inline-block won't work with the code I have.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

If you want to center them, you can't float them. A better alternative would be to make them all `display: inline-block` so you can still stylize them as a block element, and they'll still pay attention to your `text-align: center` on the parent wrapper. This would appear to be a good solution for the limited example you've provided.

In order to account for browser compatibility, you'd need to change them to `<span>` rather than `<div>` before adding the `display: inline-block` on to them. This would be supported in everything IE7 and up, and all other modern browsers. IE6 would not be supported, but [it's only widely used in China anymore](http://www.ie6countdown.com/).

Comment: Do not forget to be sure that elements are really 'float: none;'. And text-align: center; should be added to parent container (in example div#wrapper).

Answer (score 6):

```
div#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WyxHQ/1/

edit:

Moved complete code from fiddle to answer as per suggestion

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML

```
div#outer-wrapper{
border:2px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
}
```

CSS

```
div#wrapper{
    width:99px;
    margin:0 auto;
} 

div {
    width:33px;
    height:20px;
}

div.one{
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

div.two{
    background:blue;
        float:left;
}

div.three{
    background:green;
        float:left;
}
```

Comment: That would center the wrapper on the screen, I think he wants to center the floated elements *inside* the wrapper.

Comment: Then just create _another_ wrapper, the principle is the same (see fiddle)

Comment: +1, but you should move the relative code from the JSFiddle to your answer. This works only when you know the widths of the elements - which the asker does. Otherwise I would refer to @animuson's answer.

Comment: I don't consider adding additional elements *just* for styling to be a very good practice.

Comment: @animuson That is nice to hear, maybe you can link us all to your 'best practices' page and we can all learn from you. I don't consider it best practice ignoring older browsers, but I don't whine about it under your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a list and get the same results:

CSS:

```
.wrap
  {
    border:2px solid black;
    width:100%;
  }

ul
  {
    width:99px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 20px;    
  } 

ul li 
  {
    width:33px;
    height:20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

ul li.red 
  {
     background-color: red;   
  }

ul li.blue 
  {
     background-color: blue;   
  }

ul li.green 
  {
     background-color: green;   
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrap">
      <ul>
        <li class="red"> </li>
        <li class="blue"></li>
        <li class="green"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nvpXx/3/

You can wrap your floated divs with an inline-block element and center it within its parent.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="item">thing 1</div>
        <div class="item">thing 2</div>
        <div class="item">thing 3</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {width: 600px; background-color: #eee; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; text-align: center;}
#main .item {float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 5px; }
.clear {clear: both;}
.wrap { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; bordeR: 1px solid black; margin: auto;}
```

**Potential Pitfall**

This doesn't work well if you have so many floated items that they wrap to a second line.  At that point, the `div.wrap` expands to 100% of its container and as a result everything is off-center.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, keep it simple:

```
<ul>
<li> one </li>
<li> two </li>
<li> three </li>
</ul>

<style>
ul{margin:0 auto;max-width:500px}
ul li{float:left;margin:0 auto 1em;text-align:center;width:33%}
</style>
```

This will make it responsive although it breaks on some point, it helps to create a media query for the max-width:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:520px){ ul li{float:none} }
</style>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PYGDG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Floats, as the name suggests, are completely independent of their containers. So, you cannot center them according to a container, because they will know no container.

Comment: _Completely_ independent? No they're not.

Comment: Not *completely*, per se, just in the context of the question, as in their relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
<body>
    <div style="width:306px; border:#333333 1px solid; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">   
        <div style="width:100px; border:#333333 1px solid; float:left;">div A</div>
        <div style="width:100px; border:#333333 1px solid; float:left;">div B</div>
        <div style="width:100px; border:#333333 1px solid; float:left;">div C</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add a container div for them.

Then add overflow:auto so that the container div wraps around the 3 divs and then set the container div in the center with margin:0 auto.