# Centering a container of 3 float divs to the left

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs (`headcol1`, `headcol2` and `headcol3`) floated to the left:

[image: floated divs]

How do I center these 3 elements without using `padding-left` or `margin-left` in their container? The result would look the following:

[image: expected output]

```
<html>
<div class="fivestar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="headcol1">
            <p><span>FOLLOW US</span></p>
            <p>
                <a href="<?php $this->info(" fb_link ") ?>" target="_blank">F</a>
                <a href="<?php $this->info(" tt_link ") ?>" target="_blank">G</a>
                <a href="<?php $this->info(" yt_link ") ?>" target="_blank">L</a>
                <a href="<?php $this->info(" yt_link ") ?>" target="_blank">I</a>
                <a href="<?php $this->info(" yt_link ") ?>" target="_blank">X</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="headcol2">
            <img src="public/images/common/starlogo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="headcol3">
            <p><span>PHONE NO:</span></p>
            <p class="nums">
                <?php $this->info(["phone"]);?>
            </p>
            <hr width="120px">
            <p class="nums">
                <?php $this->info(["phone"]);?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<html>

<style>
    #header .fivestar {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol1 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: auto;
    }

    #header .fivestar span {
        font-family: 'myriad';
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #F24033;
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol1 p a {
        font-family: 'socialicoregular';
        font- size: 2em;
        color: #999999;
        letter-spacing: 15px
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol1 p a:hover {
        color: #AC0000;
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol2 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0px 80px 0px 80px;
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol3 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: auto;
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol3 .nums {
        font-family: 'RobotoSlab', serif;
        color: #555555;
        font-size: 1.250em;
        font- weight: bold;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #header .fivestar .headcol3 hr {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: pls help. Thank you :)

Comment: Please add your code. And also a demo if possible. There is no way we can help you with the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px; /* for demo purpose */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  border: thin solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='element'></div>
<div class='element'></div>
<div class='element'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot that the elements are floated to the left. Using margin: 0 auto: for a container will do the trick though.

Comment: But I thought margin was not allowed :) Maybe only margin-left eh

Comment: He meant that he does not want to use something like margin-left: 300px; or padding-left: 300px; `margin: 0  auto;` will be automatically and also won't  be centered for only one screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution my self.

I used display: inline-block and but col1 and col2 went down, And I don't understand why but I used vertical:align-top to put them up.

before
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CVzo.jpg

after
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdMHK.jpg

Answer (score -1):

**This question might help you:** [How to center floating divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901209/how-to-center-floating-divs)

The picture that you posted isn't working, but as far as I know, you still need to have some kind of padding or margin in order to keep your divs from touching one another. You can make this number a % so that the layout stays responsive regardless of the container `<div>` size.

Comment: A fellow told me to float col1 to the left and col3 to the right and use position:absolute for the image in the center; I haven't tried what he recommended yet but it will be my final solution if there is no really other way to do this.